# Detect the target of each element in v-for in bootstrap-vue datepicker

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

Im trying to get the `target` of each of `datepicker` rendered by `v-for`.

I need to disable different dates on each of the `datepicker` keeping in mind that the `v-for` loop is iterating over the `elements` variable which is a number that can be different in each execution .
I am using the `prop` `date-disabled-fn` to deactivate dates but I need that in each iteration this function also deactivates all the dates before the date loaded in the previous `datepicker`.

I know how to deactivate dates, but I need to know what `datepicker` I am in when executing the deactivation function in order to add the condition that deactivates dates.
This is the `v-for` loop.

```
<div v-for="elem in elements" :key="elem">
    <label :for="'datepicker' + elem" v-text="'My element ' + elem"></label>
    <b-form-datepicker
        :id="'datepicker' + elem"
        v-model="inputs.dates[elem]"
        class="mb-2"
        v-bind="labels[locale] || {}"
        :date-disabled-fn="dateDisabled"
        :locale="locale"
        :start-weekday="weekday"
    ></b-form-datepicker>
</div>
```

And this the deactivation function in `methods`

```
dateDisabled(ymd, date) {
    const weekday = date.getDay();
    const day = date.getDate();
    if(weekday === 0 || weekday === 6) {
         return true
    }
    // I want to detect the target here.

}
```

The `prop` `:date-disabled-fn` uses two arguments show I don't know how to add a third argument or if there is some way to detect the `target` in another way.

[Bootstrap-vue datepicker documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-datepicker#form-datepicker)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need to send third arguements, then can't you do

```
:date-disabled-fn="(ymd, date) => dateDisabled(ymd, date, elem)"
```

Comment: The second argument in dateDisabled function is date, but works perfectly. Thank you.